# Symfony2 Menu render algorithm

Tags: symfony

What you think about render menu algorithm?

I have 2 variants:
1. Get all menu items from database and struct them by some algorithm.
2. Get all menu items where parent is in top(parent === null) and the use recursion for get children menus from parent?

What the best variant by performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to set a RootNode who gonna have as childrens the first level of your menu then use recursivity to handle all sub-elements, this solution is perfect if you are handling a dynamic menu and you don't now how many sublevels it could have in the future,

For performance issue recursivity still a good solution, and in our case 'menu problem' I don't think that you gonna have some performance issue because you are handling relatively a very few number of items maximum you could have a menu with 100 or even 500 item which it does not cause a performance issue,

Comment: Are you think it's not problem when Entity will sending request to DB when I want to get childs from root?

Comment: you can fetch the database eagerly so you will send only one DB request which is better to prevent any redundant DB requests for each parent

Comment: I don't understand fully.

`$list = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('some:entity')->findBy(array('parent' => null));`

and than in twig

`{% macro menu(items) %}
<ul>
{% for link in items %}
<li>{{ link.title }}</li>
{{ _self.menu(link.children) }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endmacro %}`

You talk about that?

Comment: I am talking about the fetch strategy if you are using fetch lazy every time you call link.children it will request the database to get the children if the Doctrine Collection is not initialized which will probably cause some performance issues, you need to set the fetch strategy to eager then you will have all your link.children already initialized  to do so try with this <?php
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $cart;